# Why to use _this (or any other name of variable) as variable of type 'this' in angular JS or angular 2? .. How it differs with use of 'this' itself?

Tags: angularjs, angular

Why to use _this (or any other name of variable) as variable of type 'this' in angular JS or angular 2? .

How it differs with use of 'this' itself?